# Проблема с установкой Flask

Tags: python, flask

При установке Flask возникает следующая ошибка:

```
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe ... error
  Failed building wheel for MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py clean for MarkupSafe
Failed to build MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: itsdangerous, click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, flask
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", lin
tr
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 33: invalid continuation byte    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 21
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 78
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
ess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\mykola\desktop\flask-blockchain\env\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", lin
tr
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 33: invalid continuation byte
```

Python 64 бита как и система.
setuptools установил и обновил. И pip к тому же.

Comment: Это точно полный текст ошибки?

Comment: Скопировал полный текст, но думаю это не внесет ясности

Comment: Попробуйте [отсюда скачать wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#markupsafe) и установить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Ваш способ заработал

Answer (score 2):

У Flask новых версий появилась проблема - он требует установленный wheel, иначе не ставится.

Решение:

```bsh
$ pip install wheel
$ pip install flask
```

Работает для Linux и Windows