# Ошибка "No module named 'markupsafe._compat'" при первом запуске Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

При попытке выполнить:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(_name_)
@app.route("/")
def hello() -> str:
    return 'Hello world from Flask'
app.run()
```

Выдает сообщение об ошибке:

```
E:\Projects of Python\webapp>py -3 hello_flask.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 647, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from markupsafe._compat import text_type, string_types, int_types, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: возможно поможет `pip install markupsafe`

Comment: Или `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall markupsafe`; вообще, похоже что-то криво установилось, переустановка например этой командой должна что-то изменить

Comment: @andreymal выполняю pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall markupsafe получаю:   C:\Windows\System32>py -3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall markupsafe
Collecting markupsafe
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: markupsafe
  Found existing installation: MarkupSafe 1.0
    Uninstalling MarkupSafe-1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled MarkupSafe-1.0
  Running setup.py install for markupsafe ... error
  Rolling back uninstall of MarkupSafe

Answer (score 5):

Решение проблемы: [скачать wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#markupsafe), установить из директории расположения скачанного файла

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall MarkupSafe-1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

простым `pip install` не получилось. Все заработало.

Спасибо Sergey Gornostaev, помог [своим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750035/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-flask).